# Getting the information of the latest change

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, oracle12c

I have an audit table with a lot of information. I need to find when and who did the latest change to specific columns of each projects.

I was able to do the query that returns the proper result but I find it to be a giant mess. Especially since I need to do this for a lot of different columns (I'll probably do it with union) and compare those values with the latest published value. Anyway... Is there a better way than doing 3 level of select?

```
create table Z_AUDIT
(
  v CHAR(1) not null,      -- A value that is part of a project (ex: project manager)
  t DATE not null,         -- Time of change
  w VARCHAR2(10) not null, -- Who did the change
  p VARCHAR2(10)           -- Project
)

INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 1', 'a', sysdate, 'bob');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 1', 'a', sysdate-1, 'judy');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 1', 'a', sysdate-2, 'bob');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 1', 'b', sysdate-3, 'judy');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 1', 'b', sysdate-4, 'bob');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 1', 'a', sysdate-5, 'judy');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 1', 'a', sysdate-6, 'bob');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 1', 'b', sysdate-7, 'judy');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 1', 'c', sysdate-8, 'bob');

INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 2', 'b', sysdate, 'bob');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 2', 'a', sysdate-1, 'judy');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 2', 'a', sysdate-2, 'bob');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 2', 'b', sysdate-3, 'judy');
INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT (p, v, t, w) VALUES ('project 2', 'c', sysdate-4, 'bob');

 -- Get the latest change from the rank 1
 select p, w, t, current_value, previous_value
   from ( -- Get only the changes with the where clause and get the rank
         select i.p,
                 i.w,
                 i.t,
                 i.current_value,
                 i.previous_value,
                 rank() over(partition by i.p order by i.t desc) r
           from ( -- Get the previous value for each audit record
                  select p,
                          w,
                          t,
                          v as current_value,
                          LAG(v, 1) OVER(partition by p ORDER BY t) as previous_value
                    from Z_AUDIT) i
          where nvl(current_value, 'a') <> nvl(previous_value, 'a'))
  where r = 1;
```

> project 1,    bob,    5/9/2020 7:08:55 AM,    a,  b
>   project 2,    bob,    5/11/2020 7:12:39 AM,   b,  a

Comment: You did not include a full description of the logic you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of simpler ways to write this. Note I've written both using CTEs as they are easier to read (IMO). You can use `FIRST_VALUE`:

```
WITH cp AS (
  SELECT p, w, t, v AS curr,
         LAG(v, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY p ORDER BY t) AS prev
  FROM Z_AUDIT
)
SELECT DISTINCT p,
       FIRST_VALUE(w) OVER (PARTITION BY p ORDER BY t DESC) AS w,
       FIRST_VALUE(t) OVER (PARTITION BY p ORDER BY t DESC) AS t,
       FIRST_VALUE(curr) OVER (PARTITION BY p ORDER BY t DESC) AS curr,
       FIRST_VALUE(prev) OVER (PARTITION BY p ORDER BY t DESC) AS prev
FROM cp
WHERE curr != prev
```

Or the Oracle specific [`KEEP ... FIRST`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm):

```
WITH cp AS (
  SELECT p, w, t, v AS curr,
         LAG(v, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY p ORDER BY t) AS prev
  FROM Z_AUDIT
)
SELECT p,
       MIN(w) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY t DESC) AS w,
       MIN(t) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY t DESC) AS t,
       MIN(curr) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY t DESC) AS curr,
       MIN(prev) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY t DESC) AS prev
FROM cp
WHERE curr != prev
GROUP BY p
```

In both cases the output is:

```
P           W       T           CURR    PREV
project 1   bob     09-MAY-20   a       b
project 2   bob     11-MAY-20   b       a
```

Demo (alson including a CTE version of your original query) on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e87d6f87ae8f15574f3083ee4a2be0bf)

Comment: There's a lot of things I didn't know about here. I'll have to try it out tonight.